# Saving large text in CLOB with Wicket

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, wicket, clob

I want to store a large Text in my Database. For that I created the CLOB field `description` in my table and added it to hibernate like:

```
@Column
private byte[] description;
```

In Wicket I added a `Textarea` like this:

```
add(new TextArea<Object>("advisor.descriptionClob"));
```

When I click on my `AjaxSubmitLink` nothing happens (no code at all gets executed), which is a bit confusing for me, since wicket shouldn't really care about what database type I use?

Has anyone an idea what's going on here and how I fix this?

I use Wicket 6.9.1, Hibernate 4.1.7 and a MySQL database

Comment: Are you using a CompoundPropertyModel? Is the member called description or descriptionClob? Do you have a converter ready to convert between byte[] and String? Do you have a Feedback panel?

Comment: To add to @svenmeier question: do you have an onError() on your AjaxSubmitLink?

Comment: thanks for the help, I forgot to add my converter...